# Cannot sign into MSN with error code 800272ee2

Tags: windows-xp, windows-live-messenger

When trying to sign into Windows Live Messenger (2009) I receive this error:

> cannot user your contact list, please try later.800272ee2

I'm using Windows XP Professional and it looks like I have uninstalled and reinstalled MSN several times. I have tried applications like Windows Live Services Cleaner but it did not help. I have also removed the contact list folders under Application Data and that didn't work either.

What should I do with it?

Comment: Are you able to log into your Microsoft Live account through a browser?  I ran into a problem recently where my account.  I would also update your Live Messenger installation to the current version.

Comment: Some microsoft services require your computers time to be set properly. If it's off by more than 5 minutes it will prevent you from logging in to some services and provide non-useful errors.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. If you are using Windows Live Messenger, the most likely reason you are experiencing this error is because Messenger has not been able to download your contact list and you are unable to connect to the Contacts service to download your contact list. Try the following steps:
>
> A. Adjust your Microsoft Internet Explorer security settings:
>
> • Start Internet Explorer.
>
> • On the Tools menu, click Internet Options, and then click the Advanced tab. (Internet Options can also be accessed in Control Panel without starting IE)
>
> • In the Security section, make sure that the following check boxes are set correctly:
>
> 1 Clear the Check for server certificate revocation check box.
>
> 2 Select the Use SSL 2.0 check box.
>
> 3 Select the Use SSL 3.0 check box
>
> 4 Click OK to close the window.
>
> B. If you are using Windows Live Messenger on Windows Vista/W7, click on Start and type in each command one at a time in the Windows Vista search box located on the Start menu. For Windows XP click on START, select RUN and type in each command below one at a time and click the OK button. After each command is executed successfully, you will receive a "DllRegisterServer succeeded" message. Wait until you receive this message before you run the next command.
>
> • REGSVR32 softpub.dll
>
> • REGSVR32 wintrust.dll
>
> • REGSVR32 initpki.dll
>
> • REGSVR32 Rsaenh.dll
>
> • REGSVR32 Mssip32.dll
>
> • REGSVR32 Cryptdlg.dll
>
> • REGSVR32 Dssenh.dll
>
> • REGSVR32 Gpkcsp.dll
>
> • REGSVR32 Slbcsp.dll
>
> • REGSVR32 Sccbase.dll

[Source of information](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090523100330AAHz9mG)

Comment: Thanks Moab, but doesn't work also.

Comment: Dang, there is no information on that specific error code that I can find, your question might be one to post on the microsoft forums.....http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/messenger